# Is it possible to center horizontally two divs within two other divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

#### Question

I have an aside div and a main div which have some content.

[image]

Is it possible to specify that the orange box (aside content) + the blue box (the main content) are overall centered on the page and that the remaining space should be distributed equally to each side of the content?

Moreover while the aside content's width is fixed, the main content width should be responsive. Which means that while shrinking the width of the viewport:

- fist the space on the sides of each content shrinks while the content divs remain the same
- when there's no more space left on the sides, the main content shrinks

#### Limits

The answer should be limited to CSS features that have a global usage percentage of 98%+ on caniuse.com (for example [flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)). This mainly excludes CSS grids.

#### Playground

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddxWGd) you can find the above playground.

#### What I tried

I'm not sure where to start. I tried:

- `margin: auto;` on the aside content and main content
- `padding: auto;` on the content parents
- `display: inline` + `text-align:right/left`

but they all have the same problem that you either have to specify the width of the parents and you don't really have them centered.

#### A Stack Snippet for those who wish to be able to easily adapt their answer to existing code:

```css
aside,
main {
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

aside {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 1 300px;
}

aside .content {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  max-height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 1 800px;
}

main .content {
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <aside>
    <div class="content">
      Aside content
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <div class="content">
      Main content
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif The result is like in the picture except that the orange + blue box are centered. Currently the sum of that box tends on the right.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, their parents have to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. I drew inspiration from @Aivaras' answer for sizing down below `main`'s target width, but also the realization that flexbox does a lot of heavy lifting for us. I've specified the width of `aside` and `main`, but since they are `flex-basis: auto`, the width is only used as the basis of the actual width. Or so I think.

```css
aside,
main {
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

aside .content {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  max-height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
  width: 800px;
}

main .content {
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  main .content {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 999px) {
  main .content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <aside>
    <div class="content">
      Aside content
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <div class="content">
      Main content
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added margin: auto to both the orange and blue boxes.

Moreover, I gave the blue box a percentage width

```
main .content {
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%
}
```

This makes the blue box responsive.  Not sure if this is what you wanted.

Comment: "when there's no more space left on the sides, the main content shrinks"   
 - This means that only when there's no more space outside the content shrinks. With `width: 80%` there's always going to be space outside.

Answer (score 0):

Add **margin: auto** to both content divs and media query for viewport width less than 1200px to set main content width to 100% then.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px){
  .main-content{width:100%}
}
```